# making ajax call from within bootstrap modal dialog on change of an element

Tags: bootstrap-modal

```
$('#PolicyTypeId').change(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetTerm", "InsuranceSetup")';
    var value = $('#PolicyTypeId').val();
    var age = $('#Age').val();
    $.getJSON(
        url,
        { age: age, plantype: value },
        function (data) {
            if (data.result == "") {
                Notify('There was a problem with the term', 'top-left', '5000', 'danger', 'fa-desktop', true);
            }
            $('#Term').val(data.result);
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

This code is supposed to make an ajax call to get some data from a controller upon a value change on a dropdown element. However, the url is changed to the below url for the request. The customerdetails/edit/id is the url from which the modal dialog is rendered with a partial view that has a form inside.

```
http://localhost:44379/customerdetails/edit/@Url.Action(%22GetTerm%22,%20%22InsuranceSetup%22)?age=25&plantype=17
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code you posted is in the view, it looks like `Url.Action` isn't working. Make sure you have the required settings in web.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

That's normally in the Views folder.

If the code is in a JavaScript file, the url helper won't actually do anything there.